# Docker hello world not working

Tags: docker

I'm trying to start using Docker on my Linux Mint. I'm following the Hello World example, but it doesn't seem to work. Here is my log :

```
# uname -a
Linux abenoit-linux 3.8.0-31-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 10 20:03:44 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

# dpkg -l | grep docker
ii  lxc-docker                                                  0.9.0                                  amd64        Linux container runtime
ii  lxc-docker-0.9.0                                            0.9.0                                  amd64        Linux container runtime

# docker info                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Containers: 0
Images: 0
Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
 Dirs: 0
WARNING: No memory limit support
WARNING: No swap limit support

# docker pull busybox                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
Pulling repository busybox
769b9341d937: Download complete 
511136ea3c5a: Download complete 
bf747efa0e2f: Download complete 
48e5f45168b9: Download complete 

# docker ps -a                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES

# docker images                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
busybox             latest              769b9341d937        6 weeks ago         2.489 MB

# docker run busybox /bin/echo hello world                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
#
```

I can type anythin instead of "/bin/echo hello world", but I never get any output (even if the command is invalid).

Any idea what is wrong here ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just found the problem : I'm on Linux Mint where cgroup-lite is not installed by default. And when using apt-get install lxc-docker, it is only suggested and not required :

```
# apt-get install lxc-docker
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances       
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
Les paquets supplémentaires suivants seront installés : 
  aufs-tools lxc-docker-0.9.0
Paquets suggérés :
  cgroup-lite
Les NOUVEAUX paquets suivants seront installés :
  aufs-tools lxc-docker lxc-docker-0.9.0
```

So you have to install it manually.